# How to set the same CommandTimeout for all the SqlCommand with one line of code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sqlconnection

How to set the same  `CommandTimeout` for all the commands that I have created with one line of code, instead of typing in every command the `CommandTimeout` property?

This is about a `SQLConnection` .

This is the connection string that I have created:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=" + server + ";user=" + user + ";pass=" + pass + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
```

Comment: you can create a function that opens an SQL connection, and inside you set your parameters including time-out

Comment: You could create a `SqlCommandBuilder` or `SqlCommandFactory` with a method `CreateSqlCommand` that sets defaults as necessary and returns said connection

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no global way to set timeout for every command. You have to specify CommandTimeout property for each command.

Answer (score 0):

other than hijacking/detouring SqlCommand class, you can achieve same effect with an extension method.

```
public static SqlCommand CreateCommand(this SqlConnection conn, string cmdText, SqlTransaction tran = null)
        => new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn, tran) { CommandTimeout = 3000 };

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection("xyz");
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand("select 1");
    }
```